# How to implement ForeignKey with Django serializer

Tags: json, django

I have this models:

```
class Discipline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    regular_slot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And these serializers:

```
class DisciplineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Discipline
        fields = ('name')

class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    discipline = serializers.RelatedField(source='Discipline', read_only=True);
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('discipline', 'date', 'regular_slot')
```

I have a view to process a JSON request and to save the data:

```
def cours_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = LessonSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)

    return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

My JSON request is as follows:

```
 {"discipline":"Mathematiques","date":"2017-12-03"}
```

However, I have an error saying that:

> 'Lesson' object has no attribute 'Discipline'

I believe this is because attribute `discipline` in `Lesson` refers only to the id and is not of type `Discipline`. I could'nt find how to solve this. Is the way I define foreignKey is not correct ?

How to insert a foreignKey reference here while I receive a `Discipline` object from the JSON request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to help you also with this :)

```
class DisciplineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Discipline
    fields = ('name')

class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
discipline = DiscliplineSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = Lesson
    fields = ('discipline', 'date', 'regular_slot')
```

Doing this is enough as far as I know.

Edit: Reason of your error is that you write "source="Discipline"" but there is no field named Discipline in your Lesson model. Therefore, it gives an error.

Comment: Thank you Bann for your answer. Now I have another error: `{"discipline":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."]}}`

Comment: can you change your json like this? {"discipline": [{"discipline":"Mathematiques","date":"2017-12-03"}]}  It says it need a dictionary, not a str

Comment: Now it says : `Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str`

Comment: Then Actually i don't know. Can you change the code to your first version and in RelatedField(source='discipline') . Maybe this will solve the attribute error but I'm now sure because I didn't do such process in my project.

Comment: After a year, I learned some stuff. In DisciplineSerializer, fields need to be an array. ('name') is recognized as a string. Adding a comma solved the issue: ('name',). Thanks !

Comment: @Spider that structure is not array by the way :) it is tuple.